# How to run eval() function on codeblock generated from quill.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eval, quill

I am trying to let the user input the codeblock in a stylish way and save them to run later. For that purpose I found quill. But the code block generated by quill is text with bunch of HTML code used to style. [image]

For the code above the text generated by quill is

```
"<pre class=\"ql-syntax\" spellcheck=\"false\">console.log('hello world') ;\nif(2&lt;3 &amp;&amp; 2+6==8)\n{\n  alert('i am an alert') \n}\n</pre>"
```

So how can I omit all the unnecessary texts and get only the code I have written as above so that I could on eval() function on the generated string ?

Comment: Is there any library for it ?

Comment: You should probably have something to remove al the escape and encoding via quill (something like `raw` or alike). Otherwise, you could do it yourself with a quick `replace` or even a regex. Be careful on evaluating such things tho.